# I need a count of the number of rows that have a value in each of two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say I have two columns   B2:B21 and T2:T21
I need the total number of rows that have a value in both column B and T

If B2 has a value of 15, and T2 is blank, don't count that row
If B2 is blank and T2 has a value of 5, don't count that row
If B2 is blank and T2 is blank, don't count that row
If B2 is 45 and T2 is 50, then count this row (+1)

id this clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time try Super Users when you do not need programming assistance.

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B21,">0",T2:T21,">0")
```

Comment: Sorry, I've seen other Excel function questions here, but I will keep that in mind. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count a row if for example, B2 has 0 and T1 has 15 (+1), then use this instead:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"<>"&"",T:T,"<>"&"")
```

This also works for cells containing text.

Comment: Thanks, in my case, user2140261's answer is what I needed, but your point is taken.

Comment: @GeneM. It's okay, you question didn't make mention of how zeroes should be considered, so that's why I thought it might be worth suggesting that solution :)